# Raphael icon size

Tags: javascript, raphael, graphael

I have a couple Raphael icons in my website like this:

```
var emailIcon = Raphael("js-email-icon");
    emailIcon.path('M28.516,7.167H3.482l12.517,7.108L28.516,7.167zM16.74,17.303C16.51,17.434,16.255,17.5,16,17.5s-0.51-0.066-0.741-0.197L2.5,10.06v14.773h27V10.06L16.74,17.303z').attr({fill: '#ff00ff', stroke: "none"});
```

How can I make the icon bigger?

Thanks!

mb

Answer (score 3):

Use the transform method: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform

For example, to make it 150% of its normal size:

```
var emailIcon = Raphael("js-email-icon");
var iconPath = emailIcon.path('M28.516,7.167H3.482l12.517,7.108L28.516,7.167zM16.74,17.303C16.51,17.434,16.255,17.5,16,17.5s-0.51-0.066-0.741-0.197L2.5,10.06v14.773h27V10.06L16.74,17.303z').attr({fill: '#ff00ff', stroke: "none"});
iconPath.transform("s1.5");
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Ok, realized that you probably aren't using jQuery which is where .css() comes from.

I would recommend using jquery and try:

```
$(emailIcon.path('M28.516,7.167H3.482l12.517,7.108L28.516,7.167zM16.74,17.303C16.51,17.434,16.255,17.5,16,17.5s-0.51-0.066-0.741-0.197L2.5,10.06v14.773h27V10.06L16.74,17.303z').attr({fill: '#ff00ff', stroke: "none"}) ).css({width: "500px", height: "500px"});
```

I'm just wrapping everything up to `attr` like so `$(...).css({width:'500px',height:'500px'})`

or

```
$(emailIcon.path(...).attr({fill...stroke...})).css({width:'500px',height:'500px'});
```

If you don't want to use jQuery, then AS LONG AS the Rapheal .attr() function RETURNS A DOM ELEMENT, you can do:

```
var tmp = emailIcon.path(...).attr({fill...stroke...});
tmp.style.width= '500px';
tmp.style.height= '500px';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an actual svg file to work with, the easiest method I would suggest is to use a program such as Adobe Illustrator or [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org) in order modify the size of the icon.  Once this is done, just extract the path information and voila a larger icon will appear.

These programs will do all of the messy path calculations for you and also let you see how it looks before applying the code.  However, be careful when using Inkscape, because sometimes it does not modify the path and just adds a transform to the object which does nothing for us Raphael users.